# How to remove Google Chrome error popup - "your preferences cannot be read..." on Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome

Since past few days, whenever I start Google Chrome, I have been getting this popup error message saying "your preferences cannot be read..." I haven't faced any issues in normal browser usage, but I am not able to remove this error.

My OS version is Ubuntu 13.10. 
Chrome version is 36.0.1985.143.

Any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: There are a couple of solutions here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499189

Comment: Same problem here in 14.10.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I opened the folder .config/google-chrome to do as suggested in Tim's answer and happened to notice a file "Local State" whose group and owner was root and the file had a date stamp of the day since when the problem had started.

I changed the group and owner to self and the error got resolved.

Comment: I was trying the same but with no luck. I tried to change file's permissions and delete the file but both with no success. All actions performed as root. Seems this file is corrupted at the file system level (btrfs in my case).

Answer (score 9):

Try the following command:

```
mv .config/google-chrome/Default .config/google-chrome/Default.org
```

That will move your config files to a backup file, and should get rid of the problem. Then you can sign into chrome again to get everything back.

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: I don't sign in to chrome, i.e., I never sign in to chrome.

Comment: Right, sign in, wait for sync, execute the command, then sign in to the blank chrome. Wait for sync again, and then sign out, and (optionally) wipe the data from your google account.

Comment: Thanks Tim, however, paranoid as I am I won't sign in to chrome. Anyway my issue got resolved with the useful pointer from you.

Comment: Good, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Close chrome
2. Remove `/home/yourUSERNAME/.config/chromium`
3. Start up chrome

Comment: You only need to remove the preferences file. Also, it might be better to reword what you wrote, somebody new to Ubuntu might quickly scan you comment and try rm ~/.config which would be really unfortunate.